# sas calculation in table

Tags: sas, radix

I have a dataset like this:

```
data a;
input a  b $ c;
cards;
3   +   5
4   +   4
5   -   2
6   *   5
7   /   2
;run;
```

I want add a new column `D` that calculates its value from columns `A`, `B`, and `C`:

```
A   B   C   D
=== === === ===
3   +   5   8
4   +   4   8
5   *   2   10
6   -   5   1
7   /   2   3.5
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this.

```
data a;
   input a  b $ c;
   select(b);
      when('+') d=a+c;
      when('-') d=a-c;
      when('*') d=a*c;
      when('/') d=a/c;
      otherwise;
      end;
   cards;
3   +   5
4   +   4
5   -   2
6   *   5
7   /   2
;;;;
   run;
```

Comment: I wonder if there's a datastep equivalent of `%sysevalf`?

Comment: @RobertPenridge not but you can call it with the RESOLVE function.  The value returned will be character.